# using get method fetching html data, getting wrong response result

Tags: jquery, jquery-get

I am using jQuery get method to load html's data to store in to my array, for that i use this method:

```
var temps = function(views){
    var tempts = [];
    $.each(views, function(i,view){
    if(view){
        tempts.push($.get("templates/" + view + ".html"), function(data){
        console.log(data);//i am not getting response text.. getting array object.
    })
}

})
```

while i console the data i am getting a array object as like this:

```
[Object { readyState= 4,  responseText="<div id="login">\n  <form...eldset>\n   </form>\n</div>",  status=200,  more...}, function()]
```

what is wrong here... how to get response text directly..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the callback is defined outside the $.get call

Try:

```
tempts.push($.get("templates/" + view + ".html", function(data){console.log(data);}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're not actually handling the response at all...you're just sending the GET request out into thin air.

In order to handle the response you need to pass a callback function to `$.get` (called the "success" callback because it's the function that's run if the request returns successfully):

```
$.get("templates/" + view + ".html", function(data) {
    //do something with data
});
```